# x and y must be the same size Error - K- Means Scatter Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a scatterplot that shows centroids and clusters based off the K-means algorithm running on my data set. So, it should look like something like this: 
[image: Scatter Plot Example]

However, my code keeps throwing a x and y must be the same size error. Here is the function that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def thefunction(filedata, centroids, labels, cmap_name='seaice_2'):
        df = pd.read_table('filedata',sep=' ', index_col= 0, skiprows = 6).iloc[:, 0:].dropna()
        values = df.values.reshape((len(df),2))
        centroids,labels = vq.kmeans2(values, 3, minit='points')
        plt.plot()
        plt.xlim([0, 10])
        plt.ylim([0, 10])
        plt.title('Dataset')
        plt.scatter(centroids, labels)
        plt.show()
        #   create new plot and data
        plt.plot()
        X = np.array(list(zip(centroids, labels))).reshape(len(centroids), 2)
        colors = ['b', 'g', 'r']
        markers = ['o', 'v', 's']
        # KMeans algorithm
        K = 3
        kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=K).fit(X)
        plt.plot()
        for i, l in enumerate(kmeans_model.labels_):
            plt.plot(centroids[i], labels(df1)[i], color=colors[l], marker=markers[l],ls='None')
            plt.xlim([0, 10])
            plt.ylim([0, 10])
            plt.show()
```

The data or 'values' that I'm using looks like this:

```
array([[20.,   20.],
       [30., 30.],
       [ 40.,  40.],
       [50., 50.],
       [60., 60.],
       [70., 70.]
```

The kmeans algorithm that runs on the data returns something like this:

```
centroids,labels = vq.kmeans2(values, 2, minit='points')
centroids, labels
(array([[10.123, 20.232       ],
        [27.526, 18895]]),
 array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

The stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-fa95f1dffabc> in <module>()
     24 plt.ylim([0, 10])
     25 plt.title('Dataset')
---> 26 plt.scatter(centroids, len(df1))
     27 plt.show()
     28 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3376                          vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha,
   3377                          linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts,
-> 3378                          edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
   3379     finally:
   3380         ax._hold = washold

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1718         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1719         if pre_doc is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   3953         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   3954         if x.size != y.size:
-> 3955             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   3956 
   3957         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Comment: Would you please indent your code properly? And it looks like you missed a ' in `cmap_name='seaice_2`.

Comment: I updated the code. Hope that helps!

Comment: You haven't fixed the indenting in your code so it's impossible to tell what is part of `thefunction()`. In addition, I can't see anywhere in your code where you actually call that function, or a stack trace showing which line in your code is throwing the error. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include a full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Okay, I definitely indented the code and pasted the stack trace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), the first two arguments of `plt.scatter` should be x- and y-coordinates of the points.

In your code,

```
plt.scatter(centroids, labels)
```

you are telling the function that `centroids` and `labels` are the x- and y-coordinates.

What you would like to do should be something like

```
plt.scatter(values[:,0], values[:,1], c=labels)       # Original points
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], c=[0, 1]) # Clusters centroids
```